# Rails ActiveRecordRelation get all the referenced entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm currently developing a Ruby on Rails application and have run into an issue I'm not able to solve yet.
I'm going to build a Tag System from scratch like the one built by Ryan Bates (see here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging?view=asciicast)

So I'm going nuts on this one:

Lets say I have the following models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end


class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :post
end


class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :things, through: :taggings
end
```

I now have an index-Page where I display all the posts. I also want to display all the tags associated to all the posts being displayed on the page.

What I've accomplished so far is that I can include all the tags while loading the posts:

```
# posts_controller/index.rb
def index
  @posts = current_user.posts.includes(:tags)
end
```

But when I loop through the tag, I get duplicates.

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  = raw post.tags.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ')
```

Does anyone have a solution for this one? How can I load all the tags associated to a collection of posts.

Here, I've described a solution for my problem in SQL, perhaps someone can help me.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tags INNER JOIN taggings ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE taggings.post_id IN (1, 2, 3, ...) // The Post IDS
```

Thank you in advance!

Philipp

Comment: So the problem is "duplicates"?

Comment: Just add uniq before map, and it should work as you expect. 
post.tags.uniq.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set another instance variable in your controller which collects all the unique tags by calling `uniq`, e.g:

```
def index
  @posts = current_user.posts.includes(:tags)
  @tags = @posts.map(&:tags).flatten.uniq
end
```

As an aside, if you wanted to generate the SQL you specified in Ruby, you could do so like this:

```
Tag.joins(:taggings).where(:taggings => { :post_id => @posts }).uniq
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for. Never heard of .flatten btw :-D

Answer (score 1):

Rails code equivalent to your sql is,

```
Tagging.find_all_by_post_id(@posts.map{|p| p.id})
```

with where

```
Tagging.where(:post_id => @posts.map(&:id))
```

Comment: dynamic finders are deprecated, so use "Tag.where" instead

Comment: The issue here is that `Tag` does not have a `post_id` column, he will need to join with the taggings table and use `taggings.post_id`

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. I have modified my query so that there'll be only distinct values and landed by @lmars solution!

Comment: yes, you are right. You need to find this with Tagging model instead